# C macro expansion

Tags: macros

I am attempting to create a set of macros for a library to make digital I/O on an embedded processor (GNU compiler) simpler for new users.  Here is what I have so far:

```
[code]

    #define 1 A4            // this is so that I can refer to I/O 
    #define 2 B5            // by reference number 1-55

    // ****************************************************
    // I/O #defines
    // ****************************************************
    #define OUTPUT(pin) JOIN(TRIS, pin) = 0
    #define JOIN(a, b) (a ## b)
    #define HIGH(pin) JOIN(R,pin) = 1

    #define SWITCH3     1
    #define LED3        2

    OUTPUT(LED3);
    HIGH(LED3);
[/code]
```

OUTPUT(LED3) should result in:  (TRISA4) = 0;
HIGH(LED3) should result in:    (RA4) = 1;

but what I am getting is:

(TRIS1) = 0;
(R1) = 1;

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have a hunch that macros starting with a number is a bad idea - or not valid.

Comment: Never ever use such defines: #define 1 A4

Answer (score 1):

Lets run it through the compiler and see what it says:

```
$ gcc -E code.c
# 1 "code.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "code.c"
code.c:1:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
 #define 1 A4            // this is so that I can refer to I/O 
         ^
code.c:2:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
 #define 2 B5            // by reference number 1-55
         ^
# 14 "code.c"
(TRIS2) = 0;
(R2) = 1;
```

That seems pretty clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

In C (as well as in C++), macro names are required to follow the rules for identifiers – and these are required to start with an alphabetic character (upper or lower case does not matter) or an underscore.

Even if it was allowed, your macro would be extremely dangerous, as any single standing number 1 (one) would be replaced by the macro, as here:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; ++i)
```

Additionally, this name is not very informative. '1' could mean anything, an initial index into an array (if indices before are reserved for any other purpose), LPT1, ... Give your macros proper, informative names so any one reading them anywhere in your code gets a hint what they actually stand for (this applies for all identifiers: variables, functions, macros, ...). In your case something like `IO1`, `DIGITAL_IO_1`, `DIO1`, ... (for the index example above: one could call it `FIRST_OF_<some_functional_description>` or `START_<description>`).